# VUEJS - autoplay multiple videos all together after loading them

Tags: vue.js, video, onload, autoplay

Is there a way on VUEJS to autoplay multiple HTML5 videos together after all loads?
They have "autoplay" attribute but are playing with some lag.

```
        <div
          class="video-box"
          v-for="(item, index) in videoArr"
          :key="index"
          @click="playVideo"
        >
          <video
            class="video-box img-absolute"
            muted=""
            loop=""
            playsinline=""
            autoplay
            :poster="item.poster"
          >
            <source :src="item.src" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
```

Comment: please add some codes with more details

Comment: I just added some code

Comment: How about using the ```loadeddata``` event to play all videos at once when they are loaded?
[HTMLMediaElement: loadeddata event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event)

Comment: @M_YK I used this feature, but it means that when a particular video is fully loaded, it will start playing. But I want, when all the videos are loaded, only after that start the play function for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I think the lag comes from your browser or internet connection. Under normal conditions all videos should load and start at the same time, but when you get lag it comes from your interenct connection or browser.

A solution might be to load the videos async and then display them, or you could clean your browsers cache. this might make it a bit faster while loading. Also try out another browser, sometimes specific browsers handel videos or data agregation differently so compare another browser to your current one.

Comment: I've checked it on several computers and in different browsers, but the problem is the same everywhere. They are the same videos and it is obvious that some videos are playing with a lag.

Comment: Well it could mean that the service throw which you are getting the videos is the one lagging. Can I ask you where you get your videos from?

Comment: I'm getting these videos from the server. I used loadeddata event, but it means that when a particular video is fully loaded, it will start playing. But I want, when all the videos are loaded, only after that start the play function for all of them

Comment: A suggestion from me would be to load the videos as you do now, but all the video players are inside a div that you can then only show when all videos have fully laoded. You should also have a look at the async functions available in vue, here is an npm package that might help https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-async-function and you could read up on the vue documentation here https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html . Basicly I think that you need to make components out of the videos and make them async and only show them when they have loaded.